# Generic function to concatenate strings from multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

ERP used in our company (SysPro) stores narrations in multiple records (One record per line).
I’m trying to come up with generic function to return all lines as one text variable with line breaks between records. I’d like it to be the UDF to use it in “SELECT” statements and be generic so I wouldn’t have to write separate function for each “Narration” table.

I need to find a way to replace `EXEC @sql` with something else because I get an error:

> Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'EXECUTE STRING' within a
>   function

Currently we use SQL Server 2008R2

```sql
-- ================================================
-- Template generated from Template Explorer using:
-- Create Scalar Function (New Menu).SQL
--
-- Use the Specify Values for Template Parameters 
-- command (Ctrl-Shift-M) to fill in the parameter 
-- values below.
--
-- This block of comments will not be included in
-- the definition of the function.
-- ================================================
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date, ,>
-- Description: <Description, ,>
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION fnGetMultiRecordString 
(
      @table VARCHAR(256) ,
      @field VARCHAR(256) , 
      @where VARCHAR(256) , 
      @order VARCHAR(256) 
)
RETURNS  VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE 
      @sql VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE 
      @result VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE 
      @selecteddata VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = 'Declare  users_cursor CURSOR FOR  SELECT ' + @field + ' as [data] FROM ' + @table + ' WHERE ' + @where + ' ORDER BY ' + @order;

EXEC (@sql);

OPEN users_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM users_cursor INTO 
                            @selecteddata;

WHILE @@fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN
    SET @result = @result + @selecteddata + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);
    FETCH NEXT FROM users_cursor INTO 
                               @selecteddata;
END;
CLOSE users_cursor;
DEALLOCATE users_cursor;

RETURN @result

END
GO
```

Comment: why can't this be a proc?

Comment: Avoid generic functions or procedures. They're a recipe for disaster in SQL. You'll be better by learning the following method. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/comma+separated+list/71700/

Comment: It's even better when you use a snippet to build the code. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/using-code-snippets-in-ssms

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits need to use result in SELECT

Answer (score 0):

Your two choices are:

1. Write a separate function for each possible table, or
2. Make this a stored procedure instead of a function.

You're not going to be able to do dynamic sql in a function, and you can't use parameters for table names or column names without dynamic sql.

Comment: I was afraid of this. Thanx for confirmation.